# Protractor iframe element is not found / not visible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, protractor

I am writing an e2e test with Protractor that requires accessing an iframe element within an Angular 2 application.

I believe I have successfully switched into the iframe, but for some reason, the element I wish to select throws an error in my test of either "no element found with css id selector...." or "element is not visible."

Here is my code:

```
this.fillOutInfo = function(input){

 this.selectBox.click().then(function(){
    browser.switchTo().frame(this.selectBox)
     .then(function(){
        browser.findeElement(by.id('recurly-hosted-input-field')).sendKeys(input)
        .then(function(){
            browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
            })
         })
      })
   } //selectBox references the iframe element within the DOM
```

The id above is clearly there in the code when I inspect element, but for some reason it is not being accessed. Is my function implemented incorrectly? I have already tried different methods of finding the input I need, such as nested locators, but nothing has worked.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have u console.log in the nested `then`?How u resolving promise in protractor?

Comment: You have mentioned as `browser.findeElement`. is it a typo?

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj yes, sorry that is a typo on stackoverflow, not in actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research and experimentation, I arrived at a solution that worked for me. Here it is:

```
 this.fillOutInfo = function(input){

 this.selectBox.click().then(function(){
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.switchTo().frame(0)
     .then(function(){
        element(by.id('recurly-hosted-input-field')).sendKeys(input)
        .then(function(){
            browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
            })
         })
      })
   }
```

I think the two things were: 1.) adding the ignoreSyncronization and 2.) Switch frame contexts based on indexes rather than locators.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not a typo error as pointed by sudharsan selvaraj, then try

```
element.all(by.id('recurly-hosted-input-field')).count().then(function(count) {
console.log("Number of elements with same id: " + count);});
```

this will let you know how many elements are there with the same id. It has happened to me too as i was working with wrong element which had the same locator property.

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for your response here. I should have mentioned earlier, there are multiple iframes, but within each, there is only one tag with the above id. I know I am selecting the correct iframe because on line one I am first clicking on it.